# Source code for Network File System

Tags: distributed-systems, filesystems

I am doing a small project which explains how operations (file open, file write etc.) are done in client side and server side in network File system. Can anyone help me out providing its source code so that i can track its operation.

It would be helpful if you can explain how the process takes place in real time.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is off-topic here: we deal with computer *science* questions, not requests for source code (see our [FAQ]). Your question might be on-topic on [SO].

Answer (score 1):

This question is very likely to be closed because it's not on topic here.

However, there is one computer science aspect to your question, which is about the design of network file systems and NFS in particular, rather than just asking for source code. To help answer *that* question, here are the main papers on NFS:

- Sandberg et al, [*Design and Implementation of the Sun Network Filesystem*](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/archive/6.824-2005/papers/sandberg-nfs.pdf), Usenix '85.
- Sandberg, [*The Sun Network File System: Design, Implementation and Experience*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.116.8621), Usenix '86.
- Palowski et al, [*NFS Version 3: Design and Implementation*](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/bos94/full_papers/pawlowski.ps), Usenix '94.
- Palowski et al, [The NFS Version 4 Protocol](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.7599&rep=rep1&type=pdf), SANE 2000.

They may be a challenging read, but they are worth it.

The best reference that I know of is Brent Callaghan's book *NFS Illustrated*. If you have access to a well-stocked university library, it should be there. Also worth mentioning is [RFC 1094](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1094), which is definitely not for the faint-hearted.

Almost all good operating system design books have a section on networked file systems, and will often use NFS as a case study. Additionally, almost all Unix-like open source operating systems (e.g. Linux, BSD, OpenSolaris derivatives) come with NFS implementations.

If you can use a search engine, they are not difficult to find, but it will probably help a lot if you have the paper handy.